# Replace cell with NULL if there is more than 2 cells of same value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query that uses CTE and joins 2 tables but 1 of them `ubytov` many times.

```
   with CTE as
(
  select Count(u.z) as Reserved, u.z as Z
  from ubytov u
  inner join klient K on  u.[text] = K.ubytov
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ubytov U2 ON u.z = U2.id WHERE u.akce = 'FF1231-00'
  group by u.z

)

SELECT U2.[text] AS [Scheme], K.name AS Name, K.surname AS Surname, U1.akce AS Event,
    U1.[text]  AS [Registered under], u1.z,
   CTE.Reserved ,(U2.x) as [Capacity], (U2.x-CTE.Reserved) as [Free beds]
          FROM klient K

          INNER JOIN ubytov U1 ON U1.[text] = K.ubytov
          INNER JOIN CTE on U1.z = CTE.Z

          LEFT OUTER JOIN ubytov U2 ON U1.z = U2.id WHERE U1.akce = 'FF1231-00'
        ORDER BY U1.[text]
```

It gives me output like this:

```
Scheme      Name    Surname  Event      Register u.  z  R.  C. FB    
1/2 SWC Jaromír Jágr    FF1231-00   Jaromír Jágr    57  3   2   -1
1/2 SWC Radim   Vrbata  FF1231-00   Jaromír Jágr    57  3   2   -1
1/3 SWC Jiří    Hudler  FF1231-00   Jiří Hudler     58  2   3   1
1/2 SWC Patrik  Eliáš   FF1231-00   Patrik Eliáš    57  3   2   -1
1+1 SWC Test    Obsazen FF1231-00   Test Obsazen    65  1   1   0
1/3 SWC Tomáš   Plekan  FF1231-00   Tomáš Plekan    58  2   3   1
```

registered u. is column Registered Under
R. is column Reserved
C. is column Capacity
FB is column Free beds

I would like to ask you as I haven't tried or even needed to achieve something like this if there is possible to display `NULL` value in scheme column if the column `Registered under` has more than 1 rows for same `registered under` cell?

Lets say that the registered under value is `Jaromir Jagr`

The output would be:

```
Scheme      Name    Surname  Event      Register u.  z  R.  C. FB    
1/2 SWC Jaromír Jágr    FF1231-00   Jaromír Jágr    57  3   2   -1
NULL    Radim   Vrbata  FF1231-00   Jaromír Jágr    57  3   2   -1
```

NULL for each row that is already mentioned for row containing particular `registered under`
So if `Jaromir Jagr` would have `Registered under` 4 rows it would be

```
Scheme      Name    Surname  Event      Register u.  z  R.  C. FB    
1/2 SWC Jaromír Jágr    FF1231-00   Jaromír Jágr    57  3   2   -1
NULL    Name Surname    FF1231-00   Jaromír Jágr    57  3   2   -1
NULL    Name Surname    FF1231-00   Jaromír Jágr    57  3   2   -1
NULL    Name Surname    FF1231-00   Jaromír Jágr    57  3   2   -1
```

And the total output of given table would be:

```
    Scheme      Name    Surname  Event      Register u.  z  R.  C. FB    
1/2 SWC Jaromír Jágr    FF1231-00   Jaromír Jágr    57  3   2   -1
NULL    Radim   Vrbata  FF1231-00   Jaromír Jágr    57  3   2   -1
1/3 SWC Jiří    Hudler  FF1231-00   Jiří Hudler     58  2   3    1
1/2 SWC Patrik  Eliáš   FF1231-00   Patrik Eliáš    57  3   2   -1
1+1 SWC Test    Obsazen FF1231-00   Test Obsazen    65  1   1   0
1/3 SWC Tomáš   Plekan  FF1231-00   Tomáš Plekan    58  2   3   1
```

May I know how should I achieve that?

I thought that applying outer apply on `registered under` would be the way but I dont know how can I check whether there already exists one row with the same `registered under`.

Thank you all for your time in adavance.

Comment: Maybe it would be possible, if you would group the result by RegisteredUnder and get Scheme as SELECT (CASE Count(*) WHEN 1 Min(Scheme) ELSE NULL), ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore my previously suggested changes to the CTE

In Your outer select ...

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN RowNum > 1 THEN NULL ELSE Scheme END AS Scheme,Name,Surname,Event,Registered_Under AS [Registered_Under]
    ,Capacity,Free_beds as [Free beds] 
FROM 
(
   SELECT U2.[text] AS [Scheme], K.name AS Name, K.surname AS Surname, U1.akce AS Event,
    U1.[text]  AS [Registered_Under], u1.z,
   CTE.Reserved ,(U2.x) as [Capacity], (U2.x-CTE.Reserved) as [Free_beds]
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY U1.[text] ORDER BY U1.[text]) RowNum
          FROM klient K

          INNER JOIN ubytov U1 ON U1.[text] = K.ubytov
          INNER JOIN CTE on U1.z = CTE.Z

          LEFT OUTER JOIN ubytov U2 ON U1.z = U2.id WHERE U1.akce = 'FF1231-00'

 )i     
 ORDER BY Registered_Under
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to run that but it creates a lot of duplicates. I think it does the `scheme * reserved` rows so instead of 1 row for  `1/3 SWC` and I get also clumn `Scheme` full of `NULL` values.

Comment: Try reverting the cte to as it was and do this in the outer select... CASE WHEN CTE.reserved>0 THEN...

Comment: I'm sorry but Im not so sure how should I achieve that. Could you please post a code?

Comment: I think your code gave NULL values to the newly created duplicates. So th rest stays as it was in my query.

Comment: Thanks so much, I tried your code but I get `Incorrect syntax newr 'PARTITION' as I havent used that before, what should I Change?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45921/discussion-between-marek-and-twrowsell)